# Negative intersection numbers

Tags: algebraic-geometry, intersection-theory

Let $X$ be a complex variety of dimension $m$ and $D_1,D_2,\dots, D_m \subset X$ irreducible divisors with $D_i \neq D_j$. Can we have $D_1 \cdot D_2 \dots \cdot D_m < 0 $ ?

The only concrete example of negative self-intersection I know is when $m=2$, and when $D_1 = D_2$ is a curve in a surface, for example the exceptional divisor of a blow-up.

Comment: There is a lot of good information here: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/162839/top-self-intersection-of-exceptional-divisors. In general, exceptional divisors tend towards negative self-intersection.

Comment: @TabesBridges : Thank you ! I assumed the $D_i$ are all distinct. Do you think there are still some examples ?

Comment: The irreducible assumption means that a given pair of divisors cannot be supported on a common irreducible hypersurface, hence their intersection has the expected codimension of $2$. We thus expect that the full intersection will be a scheme with finite support, whose length is the intersection number (so $\geq 0$). The technical description to make this precise is "dimensionally transverse," which is discussed in the first chapter of Eisenbud-Harris' *3264 and All That*: https://scholar.harvard.edu/files/joeharris/files/000-final-3264.pdf

Comment: @TabesBridges : In my case, the $D_i$ are actually highly non-transverse (the set-up is quite complicated so I can't describe it here unfortunately.) I agree that if the $D_i$ have some kind of transversality property then it should be clear that the intersection number is positive.

Comment: Can you describe a simpler example of the sort where the divisors are distinct and irreducible but not transverse?

Comment: @TabesBridges : for example, let's say locally $D_1 = \{x_1=x_2\}, D_2 = \{x_2 = x_3\}$ and $D_3 = \{x_1 = x_3\}$. In this case $D_1 \cdot D_2$ is not transverse to $D_3$

Comment: Here I would appeal to the moving lemma, Kleiman's theorem, or explicit perturbations (e.g. replace $D_3$ with $D_3'$ defined by $x_1 = x_3 + \epsilon$ for some $\epsilon \in \mathbb C$ with $0 < |\epsilon| << 1$) depending on e.g. the characteristic of the base field, presence of a group action, the weather that day, etc. And in case you aren't so familiar with it, I should mention that I don't think you can underestimate the trick of writing a divisor $D$ as a difference of very ample divisors by taking $H$ very ample, writing $D = (D + mH) - mH$, and choosing $m$ large enough.